# QR decomposition of submatrix

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I would like to ask you whether you know, given the QR decomposition $A=QR,A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$,  if it is possible to faster derive the QR decomposition of a partition of A, that contains a subset of rows of A. The reason why I am asking is that I have to apply CCA on a set of a million $B$ matrices with $B\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times K},K\in\{1,2\}$, that contain missing rows, and the same matrix A. I am using canoncorr Matlab implementation, which makes use of QR decomposition on the two matrices followed by SVD. More information on the CCA algorithm can be found at this [document](http://numerical.recipes/whp/notes/CanonCorrBySVD.pdf). There is currently a method in [Matlab](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qrdelete.html?searchHighlight=qrdelete&s_tid=srchtitle_qrdelete_1), named qrdelete, that removes a column by finding an optimal set of Givens rotations, but I would like to ask if there is a more general way to do it, with an arbitrary subset of A rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work [from Hammarling et. al (2008)](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/1192/1/qrupdating_12nov08.pdf) explains some ways with which what I was asking can be done. The main  idea here is the deletion of a number of groups of rows, so the section 2.1 summarizes plenty of ways to do this, however the computational gains I could get from this, particularly in the case of high missingness, seem to be non-existent. If I could intercalate a method that finds the best permutation of matrices B , so that the minimum number of rows is required to be added or deleted at any given iteration, namely minimizing the edit distance between sets, then I would possibly be able to get a speed-up of the total process.